# pyodbc and oracle: unicode problems

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, pyodbc

I am experiencing some problems with pyodbc and an Oracle 11.2 Express databank. I cannot send unicode objects to fill the placeholders.

I first create the connection and the cursor:

```
>>> con = pyodbc.connect('uid=oracleuser;driver={microsoft odbc for oracle};server=//localhost:1521/xe;pwd=xxx')
>>> cur = con.cursor()
```

Then I can perform some simple queries that work, like:

```
>>> cur.execute(u'SELECT * FROM MY_TEST_TABLE')
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x07C92988>
>>> list(_)
[('pepe', )]
```

Then some more complex ones with placeholders, that work as well:

```
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TEST_TABLE WHERE column1 = ?', 'lol')
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x07C92988>
>>> list(_)
[]  # No result as expected
```

But when I test the real case with unicode strings, I get the following problems:

```
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TEST_TABLE WHERE column1 = ?', u'lol')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] SQL data type out of range (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

Funny, but if the main query is unicode, it works:

```
>>> cur.execute(u'SELECT * FROM MY_TEST_TABLE WHERE column1 = ?', 'lol')
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x07C92988>
>>> list(_)
[]
```

This code worked well with SQLite and SQL Server, but it crashes with an Oracle 11.2 Express DB.

I ran the following SQL to check the encoding, and it is UTF8

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
>>> AL32UTF8
```

Problems that I found that are very related but did not bring me the answer:

- [using pyodbc on linux to insert unicode or utf-8 chars in a nvarchar mssql field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947077/using-pyodbc-on-linux-to-insert-unicode-or-utf-8-chars-in-a-nvarchar-mssql-field)
- [How do I encode Unicode strings using pyodbc to save to a SAS dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900214/how-do-i-encode-unicode-strings-using-pyodbc-to-save-to-a-sas-dataset)

I don't know how to continue... do I have to encode each unicode object I send? that's messy... and I don't have to do it with MS SQL Server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, it could be an Oracle bug.  If you were on SE or EE, I'd suggest you upgrade to 11.2.0.4.0, but, as you are on XE, that's not an option.  If you have an opportunity to test on 11.2.0.4.0 on SE or EE, I'd recommend you do that, just to see if you can rule out a bug.

Comment: I have tried it in a colleague's machine with Oracle 11.2.0.1 SE and the problem is still there.

Comment: Well, that's not a surprise, since that's the same version....see if your colleague is willing to upgrade to 11.2.0.4, (which he really should, 11.2.0.1 is really old now, and there have been many, many bug fixes since the 11.2.0.1 initial release of 11gR2.)

Comment: It seems for the moment is not possible for him to update... as a provisional workaround I can compose manually the SQL.